# oil exponent in transformers (oil-filled transformers)

Tags: transformer

The oil exponent *n* is said to depend upon the cooling state. In other words, it is an empirically desired coefficient selected for cooling mode to approximately account for a change in the resistance with load.

My doubt here is that suppose I have an oil natural air natural type of transformer. Then *n* will be around 0.8.

But if the weather where the transformer is becomes extremely windy, then in that case, am I supposed to take the *n* value corresponding to oil natural forced air type of transformer (i.e. n = 0.9-1) since the wind kind of acts as forced air on the transformer ?

Does this *n* value ever change for a particular transformer ?

I am talking about this *n* (encircled in blue and the definition of which is highlighted in yellow) :

[image: this]

The paper "Modelling of Oil-filled Transformer" by Marius-Constantin O.S. Popescu, Nikos E. Mastorakis, Liliana N. Popescu-Perescu had this table explaining the value of *n* in different cases :

[image: this]

I just wish to understand this oil exponent parameter and will it ever change based on conditions that the transformer is subjected to.

I wish to understand the factors on which this parameter depends. When I am calculating the top-rise oil temperature (as in the above equation), I believe , that *n* is subject to change depending upon the environment the transformer is in. If the transformer is indoors, then the ONAN transformer will function normally and the *n* value can be safely assumed to be constant. However, if its an outdoor transformer , then the weather conditions change. For instance, we can have a very windy type of weather which can act as the fan used for cooling in case of Oil Natural Air Forced (ONAF) transformers. So, while doing the computations, will the *n* value still remain same or will it change ?

Comment: For which property?

Comment: @winny, I am talking about the parameter n (oil exponent).  I wish to understand the factors on which this parameter depends. When I am calculating the top-rise oil temperature (as in equation 13), I believe , the n is subject to change depending upon the environment the transformer is in. If the transformer is indoors, then the ONAN transformer will function normally and the n value can be safely assumed to be constant.

Comment: However, if its an outdoor transformer , then the weather conditions change. For instance, we can have a very windy type of weather which can act as the fan used for cooling in case of Oil Natural Air Forced (ONAF) transformers. So, while doing the computations, will the n value still remain same or will it change ?

Comment: PARAMETER OF WHICH PROPERTY? Dielectric constant? Breakdown withstand? Volume resistivity? Viscosity? Refractive index?

Comment: n is a thermal parameter defined in respected to the refrigeration method used for oil-filled transformers. Its not related to the properties like the ones you state. You can understand it as the property of the transformer being used.

Comment: Huh? What "oil exponent"? Your "n" term is undefined.  You really should have been able to see this yourself.  Closing as *unclear*.

Comment: Looks to me like you'd only use the forced air factor only if you provide a fan to **guarantee** the airflow.  Natural airflow will vary out of your control, so you assume the worst case.  Else, your transformer explodes because you got a hot, windless day.

Comment: Please refer to table 1 here  - > www.naun.org/main/NAUN/ijmmas/19-166.pdf

Comment: N is a design factor.  It doesn't change from day to day.  It is an assumption (or a requirement) that you choose at design time.

Comment: It talks about a thermal parameter, "Oil exponent" , often denoted by n in many papers related to doing calculations for  top-oil temperature of the oil in the transformer. I wished to have a clarity on that

Comment: You should quote (or post a picture of) the relevant text.  Lots of folks won't take the time to go looking for the relevant section in a linked document.  And why should they?  They are helping you, so you should make it as easy as possible for them.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, sorry about that. Will take care of it next time. I am a novice here.

Comment: @JRE, I understand. Extremely sorry about that. Will take care of it next time. Thanks again for all the help !

Comment: You can edit your question, and improve it (add the relevant text, etc.). Then, you stand a much better chance of someone knowledgeable about transformers answering.  All I've provided are comments based on nothing more than a good understanding of English.  I know absolutely jack about transformers, so you really need an answer from someone qualified to give one.

Comment: Next time isn't good enough.  If you want to keep this question from getting closed, you need to fix this question.

Comment: edited. Hope this will do.

Comment: Much better! Oil temperature was the property we are talking about. Retracting close vote.

Comment: Much better.  Upvoted.